# SQL Windows Login in Web Application

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I'm developing a web application which will be hosted in remote server and would like to add an Test Connection button for SQL DB.
The SQL authentication method works perfectly but I wanted to know is there any way I can add windows authentication method too.
If I use

```
connectionString="data source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;"
```

It will take Username and Creds of hosted server instead of end users.

Is there any way to test connection of SQL Database located in end users personal system by a web application which is hosted in some other server?

Comment: When you use windows authentication, the local system user account (AppPool Identity) will be used to authenticate against the target SQL server. So the SQL server can authenticate this user as long as it knows this user. If the application server and the SQL server are in different network, this will not work. Windows Authentication is best used when the db server and the users belong to the same AD and db server and authenticate the user against the AD.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: What you need to do is impersonate your database access code. Funtionality of different web frameworks change what and how it can be done (**and you are missing tags in your question**). In clasic webforms you can impersonate the visiting user editing the web.config. In Asp.net Core that is not possible but you can code [impersonate in asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation)

Comment: If you add impersonation you will not need to add windows authentication (users visiting your site will already be authenticated), you would only need to check for authoritation. Do note authoritation changes a lot in different web frameworks, and your question lacks a bit information, namely what web framework you are using. IMHO it would benefit if you [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72724908/edit) and improve its tags.

Comment: @Cleptus That does depend on whether they are using Windows to begin with